# Conditional counting in R

Tags: r

I have a question I hope some of you might help me with. I am doing a thesis on pharmaceuticals and the effect from parallelimports. I am dealing with this in R, having a Panel Dataset

I need a variable, that counts for a given original product - how many parallelimporters are there for this given time period.

```
Product_ID     PI     t    
    1          0      1
    1          1      1
    1          1      1
    1          0      2
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    2          0      1
    2          1      1
    2          0      2
    2          1      2
    2          0      3
    2          1      3
    2          1      3
    2          1      3
```

Ideally what i want here is a new column, like number of PI-products (PI=1) for an original (PI=0) at time, t. So the output would be like:

```
Product_ID     PI     t     nPIcomp
    1          0      1        2
    1          1      1
    1          1      1
    1          0      2        4
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    2          0      1        1
    2          1      1
    2          0      2        1
    2          1      2
    2          0      3        3
    2          1      3
    2          1      3
    2          1      3
```

I hope I have made my issue clear :)

Thanks in advance,
Henrik

Comment: +1 for giving a working example and desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
x <- read.table(text = "Product_ID     PI     t    
    1          0      1
    1          1      1
    1          1      1
    1          0      2
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    1          1      2
    2          0      1
    2          1      1
    2          0      2
    2          1      2
    2          0      3
    2          1      3
    2          1      3
    2          1      3", header = TRUE)

find.count <- rle(x$PI)
count <- find.count$lengths[find.count$values == 1]
x[x$PI == 0, "nPIcomp"] <- count

   Product_ID PI t nPIcomp
1           1  0 1       2
2           1  1 1      NA
3           1  1 1      NA
4           1  0 2       4
5           1  1 2      NA
6           1  1 2      NA
7           1  1 2      NA
8           1  1 2      NA
9           2  0 1       1
10          2  1 1      NA
11          2  0 2       1
12          2  1 2      NA
13          2  0 3       3
14          2  1 3      NA
15          2  1 3      NA
16          2  1 3      NA
```

Comment: I just tried your solution - But i didn't quite get the solution all the way :)

I have taken a screendump of the code I used:http://cl.ly/image/0q1T062M0r2T

also for the record: my dataset is 'IMS' Product_ID is called 'gid' and PI is called 'pi' (I couldn't remember the names of the variables when i wrote earlier, i was sitting at work)

As you can se from dataset: http://cl.ly/image/3p2I2W0M1m0f , i haven't gotten a new variable called 'nPIcomp' after sourcing the code. This is ideally what i wanted. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: @Hbrandi You're not suppose to get a new variable. This should add another column into your `IMS` object.

Comment: I tried your example, and when i source those lines it works perfectly fine. However, when I apply it to my real dataset, using this code:

find.count <- rle(IMS$pi)
count <- find.count$lengths[find.count$values == 1]
IMS[IMS$pi == 0, "nPIcomp"] <- count

I get this error:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, IMS$pi == 0, "nPIcomp", value = c(1L,  : 
  replacement has 14297 rows, data has 247603

Comment: @Hbrandi without seeing your data, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ave` and your two columns `Product_ID` and `t` as grouping variables. Then, within each group, apply a function that returns the sum of PI followed by the appropriate number of `NA`s:

```
dat <- transform(dat, nPIcomp = ave(PI, Product_ID, t,
                                    FUN = function(z) {
                                      n <- sum(z)
                                      c(n, rep(NA, n))
                                    }))
```

The same idea can be used with the `data.table` package if your data is large and speed is a concern.

Comment: This was my first idea, but then opted for rle. My solution breaks if PI traverses Product_IDs. Given the panel data, this seems unlikely, but you never know...

Answer (score 1):

Roman's answers gives *exactly* what you want. In case you want to summarise the data this would be handy, using the `plyr` pacakge (`df` is what I have called your `data.frame`)...

```
ddply( df , .(Product_ID , t ) , summarise , nPIcomp = sum(PI) )
#  Product_ID t nPIcomp
#1          1 1       2
#2          1 2       4
#3          2 1       1
#4          2 2       1
#5          2 3       3
```